# codeigniter file upload not uploaded

Tags: codeigniter

upload file all data wrok properly but file upload not save in server also file name not get

view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('main/sent'); ?>" id="frm1">

<input type="file" name="userfile">

</form>
```

controller main
inside

```
public function sent(){
$config = array(
'upload_path' => "./inquery/",
'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
'overwrite' => TRUE,
'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
'max_height' => "768",
'max_width' => "1024"
);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if($this->upload->do_upload())
{
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
var_dump($data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your form is able to submit files:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>
```

Give the enctype attribute as above and you must be done!

And let the function know what field in the form your file comes from:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
...
```

Comment: also i do that still they are not work please give me example , becaues of i need upload 2 file indivisual also they not work

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading a file you need to set the `enctype` property of form element to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

and i have appended a else clause to display error if upload is not successful. So you can figure out the reason!!!

```
public function sent(){
$config = array(
'upload_path' => "./inquery/",
'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
'overwrite' => TRUE,
'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
'max_height' => "768",
'max_width' => "1024"
);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if($this->upload->do_upload())
{
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
var_dump($data);
}else{
print_r($this->upload->display_errors()));
}
```

Comment: i do that still they are not work if you have code for that so please sent me